# MaxDiff Analysis with mlogit

Tags: r

HeyGuys,

I got the following problem.
I wanted to analyse my BWS-based survey with the MaxDiff analysis.
The Survey consists of 11 attributes to be tested in 11 Sub-Sets and 5 attributes shown in each set.  (BIBS-based design)
The respondents crossed always one best and one worst attribute within a Sub-Set.
So, now I want to create a rank ordering of those attributes according to their importance.
Therefore, I found a case study with the code how to do that
http://surveyanalysis.org/wiki/Analyzing_Max-Diff_Using_Standard_Logit_Models_Using_R
However, I have problems to adjust the code to my data.
Thereby, I get several problems when running the code.

```
library(BiasedUrn)
library(foreign)
library(mlogit)
library(Formula)
library(maxLik)
library(miscTools)

bwsdata = read.csv ("C:\\Users\\martymart\\Dropbox\\BWS_Auswertung in R\\DatenCCH.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE)
fix (bwsdata)
str(bwsdata)
'data.frame':   21 obs. of  129 variables:
$ ID               : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Geschlecht       : num  1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
$ Alter            : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Bezeichnung      : num  2 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 ...
$ Mederfahrung     : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
$ Mederfahrungjm   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA ...
$ Medausbildung    : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Medausbildungende: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD1_Req1         : num  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...
$ MD1_Req2         : num  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 -1 0 ...
$ MD1_Req3         : num  -1 0 1 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 0 ...
$ MD1_Req4         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD1_Req5         : num  0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 ...
$ MD1_Req6         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD1_Req7         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD1_Req8         : num  0 0 -1 0 -1 -1 0 -1 1 0 ...
$ MD1_Req9         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD1_Req10        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD1_Req11        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD2_Req1         : num  0 -1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD2_Req2         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD2_Req3         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD2_Req4         : num  1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 ...
$ MD2_Req5         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD2_Req6         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD2_Req7         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD2_Req8         : num  -1 0 0 -1 -1 0 0 0 1 0 ...
$ MD2_Req9         : num  0 1 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
$ MD2_Req10        : num  0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD2_Req11        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD3_Req1         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD3_Req2         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD3_Req3         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD3_Req4         : num  1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 ...
$ MD3_Req5         : num  0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD3_Req6         : num  0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 ...
$ MD3_Req7         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD3_Req8         : num  -1 0 0 0 1 -1 -1 0 1 0 ...
$ MD3_Req9         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD3_Req10        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD3_Req11        : num  0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD4_Req1         : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ MD4_Req2         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD4_Req3         : num  -1 0 1 -1 1 0 -1 0 0 0 ...
$ MD4_Req4         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD4_Req5         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD4_Req6         : num  0 -1 -1 0 0 -1 0 -1 -1 -1 ...
$ MD4_Req7         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD4_Req8         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD4_Req9         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD4_Req10        : num  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD4_Req11        : num  0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD5_Req1         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD5_Req2         : num  0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD5_Req3         : num  -1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 0 ...
$ MD5_Req4         : num  1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ MD5_Req5         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD5_Req6         : num  0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 ...
$ MD5_Req7         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD5_Req8         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD5_Req9         : num  0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD5_Req10        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD5_Req11        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD6_Req1         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD6_Req2         : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 -1 0 ...
$ MD6_Req3         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD6_Req4         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD6_Req5         : num  -1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 ...
$ MD6_Req6         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD6_Req7         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD6_Req8         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD6_Req9         : num  0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 ...
$ MD6_Req10        : num  1 0 -1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
$ MD6_Req11        : num  0 -1 1 -1 -1 0 0 0 1 -1 ...
$ MD7_Req1         : num  0 0 0 0 -1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD7_Req2         : num  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
$ MD7_Req3         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD7_Req4         : num  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD7_Req5         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD7_Req6         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD7_Req7         : num  -1 0 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
$ MD7_Req8         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD7_Req9         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD7_Req10        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD7_Req11        : num  0 -1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD8_Req1         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD8_Req2         : num  0 1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
$ MD8_Req3         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD8_Req4         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD8_Req5         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD8_Req6         : num  0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 -1 ...
$ MD8_Req7         : num  -1 0 0 0 1 -1 0 0 -1 0 ...
$ MD8_Req8         : num  0 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 1 1 ...
$ MD8_Req9         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD8_Req10        : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ MD8_Req11        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD9_Req1         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD9_Req2         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ MD9_Req3         : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
[list output truncated]
#selecting the max-diff data
z = bwsdata [,-1:-8]

#stacking the data
alternativeNamesBWS = c ("Confidentiality", "Controluse", "Accesscontrol", "Integrity", "Flexibility", "Usability", "Anonymitymed", "Finegrained", "Anonymitypat", "Availability", "Revocation")
nAlternatives = length(alternativeNamesBWS)
nBlocks = ncol(z) / nAlternatives
nAltsPerSet = 5
n = nrow(z)
nObservations = n * nBlocks
bwsdataMaxDiff = matrix(as.numeric(t(z)),ncol = nAlternatives,byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(1:nObservations, alternativeNamesBWS))
```

And then, I trick the data for the aggregate logit model:

```
#before running a MNL, trick the data first
nRows = sum(is.na(bwsdataMaxDiff)) * 2
longData = matrix(0, nRows,nAlternatives + 3)
counter = 0
setCounter = 0
for (rr in 1:nObservations){
nAlts = 0
alternatives = NULL
respondent = floor(rr/nBlocks) + 1
for (cc in 1:nAlternatives){
  v = bwsdataMaxDiff[rr,cc]
  if (!is.na(v)){
      nAlts = nAlts + 1
      alternatives[nAlts] = cc
      if (v == 1)
         best = cc
      if (v == -1)
         worst = cc
  }
}
setCounter = setCounter + 1
for (a in 1:nAlts){
 counter = counter + 1
      this_a = alternatives[a]
      if (this_a == best)
 longData[counter,3] = 1
      else if (this_a == worst)
 longData[counter + nAlts,3] = 1
 longData[counter, 1] = respondent 
 longData[counter + nAlts,1] = respondent 
 longData[counter, 2] = setCounter 
 longData[counter + nAlts, 2] = setCounter + 1
 longData[counter,3 + this_a] = 1
 longData[counter + nAlts,3 + this_a] = -1
  }
 setCounter = setCounter + 1
 counter = counter + nAlts
 }
 longData[1:20,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     0     0
[5,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     0     0
[6,]    1    2    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[7,]    1    2    0    0   -1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[8,]    1    2    1    0    0   -1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[9,]    1    2    0    0    0    0    0   -1    0     0     0     0     0
[10,]   1    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0    -1     0      0
[11,]    1    3    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[12,]    1    3    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     0
[13,]    1    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     0     0
[14,]    1    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     0
[15,]    1    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1
[16,]    1    4    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[17,]    1    4    0    0    0    0   -1    0    0     0     0     0     0
[18,]    1    4    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0    -1     0     0
[19,]    1    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0    -1     0
[20,]    1    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0    -1
      [,14]
[1,]     0
[2,]     0
[3,]     0
[4,]     0
[5,]     0
[6,]     0
[7,]     0
[8,]     0
[9,]     0
[10,]     0
[11,]     0
[12,]     0
[13,]     0
[14,]     0
[15,]     0
[16,]     0
[17,]     0
[18,]     0
[19,]     0
[20,]     0

longDataBWS = as.data.frame(longData)
names(longDataBWS) = c("ID","Set","Choice",alternativeNamesBWS)


str(longDataBWS)
'data.frame':   2772 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ ID             : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Set            : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Choice         : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Confidentiality: num  1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Controluse     : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Accesscontrol  : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 ...
 $ Integrity      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Flexibility    : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 ...
 $ Usability      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Anonymitymed   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Finegrained    : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 -1 ...
 $ Anonymitypat   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Availability   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Revocation     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Problem 1 Aggregate Logit Model:

```
> logitModelBWS = mlogit(Choice ~ Controluse + Accesscontrol + Integrity + Flexibility + Usability + Anonymitymed + Finegrained + Anonymitypat + Availability + Revocation | 0, data = longDataBWS, alt.levels = paste(1:nAltsPerSet), shape = "long", method = "nr", print.level = 0)
Fehler in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1.1", "1.2", "1.3", :
invalid 'row.names' length
```

Problem 2 Tricked Random Parameters Logit Model, I got following error:

```
> longData$ID = rep(1:n,rep(nBlocks * 2 * nAltsPerSet,n))
warning:
In longData$ID = rep(1:n, rep(nBlocks * 2 * nAltsPerSet, n)) :
modify the left side in one list
>
> rpLogitModelBWS = mlogit(Choice ~ Controluse+Accesscontrol+Integrity+Flexibility+Usability+Anonymitymed+Finegrained+Anonymitypat+Availability+Revocation | 0, data = longData, alt.levels = paste(1:nAltsPerSet), shape = "long", id="ID", panel = TRUE, rpar = c(Controluse = "n", Accesscontrol = "n", Integrity = "n", Flexibility = "n", Usability = "n", Anonymitymed = "n", Finegrained = "n", Anonymitypat = "n", Availability = "n", Revocation = "n"), correlation = TRUE)
error in rep(alt.levels, n) : unvalid'times' Argument
```

Thanks for any help!

Marta

Comment: This is a problem with your data. At least post the result of str(longDataBWS), but I doubt that this will be enough to debug the complex statement of yours. Try to simplify you model and edit your post so that it contains at least some of the data you use using dput.

Comment: I do not understand what is the problem with my data since the Rank-Ordered  Logit Model with Ties (Sequential Model) works without problems for the same data.                                                           rankModel = max.diff.rank.ordered.logit.with.ties(bwsdataMaxDiff)
ranks = nAlternatives + 1 - rank(rankModel$coef)                cbind(Parameters = rankModel$coef, Ranks = ranks)